# typscript component type parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have below code

```
const pageArea = (Component,title) => ({ ...props }) => {
<Component {...props} />
}
```

This is working fine in js, but I want to change this to typescript

I tried like this

```
 function ErrorFallback({error, resetErrorBoundary}) {
  return (
    <div role="alert">
      <p>Something went wrong:</p>
      <pre>{error.message}</pre>
      <button onClick={resetErrorBoundary}>Try again</button>
    </div>
  )
}



const pageArea = (Component:ReactNode,title:String) => ({ ...props }) => {

  return (
    <>
      {/* <Header pTitle= {title} /> */}
        <div>
        <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}>
           {Component ? <Component {...props} /> : null}
        </ErrorBoundary>
        </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

But its not working,,, typescript saying error of any type

Can someone help me converting that to typescript, also I am finding it difficult to understand this arrow function syntax... if someone can suggest any link to understand that will be great...

Thanks

Comment: `its not working` how? error message? what is the message?

Comment: Thats not a valid syntax... You should try TS playground and minimal docs read

Comment: you forgot to close the curly braces at the end of title!

Comment: Thats typo mistake

Comment: please fix it via editing your post.

Comment: I have updated with full code I am trying

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to do, for example, you could define your type outside of the component and then pass it to the component:

First, you need to import the proper type from the `react` library

```
import React, {FunctionComponent, ReactNode} from 'react';
```

Now, you could define your types with `interface` which came from **TypeScript**:

```
interface PageAreaProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  title: string;
}
```

Finally, apply that interface into your component:

```
const PageArea: FunctionComponent<PageAreaProps> = ({children, title}) => { // rest of the codes}
```

**Note:** always use `uppercase` for the first letter of your component names.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";

interface Props {
  title: string
}
const pageArea = (Component: FunctionComponent<Props>, title: string) => () => {
  return <Component title={title} />
}

function Test ({ title }: Props) {
  return <h1>{title}</h1>
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {pageArea(Test, 'some')()}
    </div>
  );
}
```